# create document from c++ code from command in python

Tags: python, c++, bash, opencv

I'm working on a project using opencv. I choosed to make this project in python to ease my task. But for some tasks, python is very slow and I must code in C++ in order to have a reasonable time of execution.

My first solution was to try to use a wrapper but after two days, I couldn't manage to make it work.

I made another solution: compiling my C++ code and call it from python with a os.system command.

My code is like this:

In C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv){

    Mat src = imread(argv[1], 1);
    Mat dst = imread(argv[2], 1);

    unsigned char *sinput = (unsigned char*)(src.data);
    int lo = atoi(argv[3]);
    int up = atoi(argv[4]);
    int connectivity = 4;
    int newMaskVal = 255;
    int ffillMode = 1;
    int flags = connectivity + (newMaskVal << 8) + (ffillMode == 1 ? CV_FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE : 0);
    Rect ccomp;
    unsigned int counter = 0;
    for(int j = 0;j < src.rows;j++){
        for(int i = 0;i < src.cols;i++){
            unsigned short b = sinput[(src.cols * j * 3) + i*3 ] ;
            unsigned short g = sinput[(src.cols * j * 3) + i*3 + 1];
            unsigned short r = sinput[(src.cols * j * 3) + i*3 + 2];

            if (r == 0 and g == 255 and b == 0){
                unsigned char *dinput = (unsigned char*)(dst.data);
                unsigned short db = dinput[(dst.cols * j * 3) + i*3 ] ;
                unsigned short dg = dinput[(dst.cols * j * 3) + i*3 + 1];
                unsigned short dr = dinput[(dst.cols * j * 3) + i*3 + 2];
                if (dr != 0 or dg != 255 or db != 0){
                    floodFill(dst, Point(i,j), Scalar(0,255,0), &ccomp, Scalar(lo, lo, lo), Scalar(up, up, up), flags);
                    counter++;
                    if (counter > 100 && counter % 100 == 0){
                        cout << counter << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    imwrite("/home/gaetan/Dropbox/Projects/PyCharm/FacadeClipper/tmp/flooded.png", dst);
    cout << "Image wrote!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and in python

```
def floodFill(self):
    lo = 20
    up = 20
    cv2.imwrite("../tmp/im.png", self.img)
    cv2.imwrite("../tmp/imG.png", self.lineImg)
    os.system("./../Methods/flood ../tmp/imG.png ../tmp/im.png " + str(lo) + " " + str(up))
    time.sleep(1)
    self.floodImg = cv2.imread("../tmp/flooded.png")
    image = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(self.floodImg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    self.displayImage(image)
    os.system('rm ../tmp/im.png ../tmp/imG.png ../tmp/flooded.png')
```

but sadly, the image "flooded.png" doesn't seems to be created when I use the python code, but when I use the bash command

```
   $ ./flood /home/gaetan/ang.JPG /home/gaetan/an.JPG 20 20
```

the file is created. What am I doing wrong?

I know this solution is really gross and I'm really hesitating in recode it entirely in C++, but as it is already a very big bunch of code, I would rather not be forced to do it.

Thanks :)

Comment: have you tried using SWIG for automated bindings? it is fairly good :)

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't manage to make it work. I always had an error when making the import in python :/

Comment: What's your actual question? Are you having problems calling C++ from Python or are you having problems making the image in pure Python?

Comment: New version of `cffi` just came out that might interest you: http://morepypy.blogspot.com.au/2015/05/cffi-10-beta-1.html

Comment: Perhaps you can store this command `./../Methods/flood ../tmp/imG.png ../tmp/im.png " + str(lo) + " " + str(up)"` in a variable and print it before passing to os.system(). And after your script finishes you can try to execute it manually. Maybe it's something wrong with the file paths.

Comment: did you investigate using ctypes or Cython?

Comment: The path seems good, this doesn't seems to be the problem. The question I was asking myself was: does the command launched by os.system() happen in the python virtual machine, and then, does not modify the environment outside the virtual machine? I will look about cffi, ctypes and Cython and keep you updated. Thanks for your help :)